# Cell Rendering issue in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {headerName: 'Connection', field: 'Applicationaccess',minWidth:350,filter:'text',filterParams:{

         filterOptions:['equals','contains']

        },cellClass: 'all_grid_cell conn_cell',cellRenderer:function(params){

        var p=params.value;
        var $wrapper_div = $("<div>",{"class":"w3-dropdown-hover"});
        var $newlink=$("<a>",{"href":"javascript:void(0)","class":"link w3-white","text":p});
        $newlink.appendTo($wrapper_div);
        var $ediv = $("<div>",{"class":"w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border"});
        var x=['meet','meeeeet','meeeeeeeet'];
        for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
          var $btn=abc(x[i]);
          $btn.appendTo($ediv);       
        }
        $ediv.appendTo($wrapper_div);
        return $wrapper_div;


        }}

function abc(x){
 var $btn=$("<button>",{"class":" w3-bar-item w3-button","text":x});
 return $btn;
}
```

The output in Connection looks like [Object][object]:[image]

My target is to display a hoverable dropdown in each cell of the Connection Column.
Following the documentation I  created my desired div element and returned it via the cellRenderer function
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a JQuery guru... but it looks like one issue you are running into is that you are returning a JQuery object (which in this case seems to be an array) rather than an HTML element. Change `return $wrapper_div;` to  `return $wrapper_div[0];` and it should work.

Here is an example showing the difference of what gets returned:

```js
console.log("HTML Element:\n", $("<div>",{"class":"w3-dropdown-hover"})[0])

console.log("JQuery Object:\n", $("<div>",{"class":"w3-dropdown-hover"}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @MeetShah Looks like you are new to Stack Overflow. If this answer helped you solve your problem you can "accept" it as the correct answer, Or if this answer led you in the right direction then you can just upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Yep return $wrapper_div[0], because it's a jQuery DOM object you are returning and not a normal DOM object. 
jQuery Dom object and HTML DOM object are different read the jQuery documentation. You will understand why you can use it as an array and why you return the first element. 
Secondly why are you using $ in your variable names? This is not PHP you need not use $. 
In jQuery $ is a special keyword which is associated to a special $ function which deals with selectors and accessing jQuery DOM objects. The $ is an alias for the jQuery () overloaded function.